# Bash scripting for a lab

Tags: bash

Doing a class with writing a bash scrip for diagnostics.

the bit i'm completely stuck on is how to i only capture a specific line and segment of text in that line.

IE:   if i do an ifconfig

```
 [user@localhost ~]$ ifconfig
 ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.88.140  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
        inet6 fe80::fbaa:d42c:24db:dca7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:0c:29:bc:c1:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

I would like bash to capture line 2 column 12 to 27  for ipv4 address into a $string,  and continue to do the same for netmask, broadcast, mac address and ipv6 address/cidr...
also do the same to get out any nameservers in the resolve.conf file.

I then of course have to repeat this for each interface...

Unless someone can reccomend a better way of doing this.

I also am wondering if there is a way i can insert a $string to the ifcfg-ens33 file to change the IP address (and everything else)  or am i best off completely recreating the file?

i think with this information i should be able to do the rest of the prac quite easily

EDIT:
I can see i need to do something with fields, but i can work out how to make it only do field 2 of line 2 into $ipv41

EDIT2:
i have come up with this after more reading.   but i cant get the output to go into the variables so far.  tried echo, printf, >, >>, >>>

```
#import settings from ip command
#discover interface type into string
/sbin/ip -o -4 addr show up primary scope global| awk '{print $2}' | echo > 
$if1

#discover interface ipaddress by interface type into strings
/sbin/ip -o -4 addr show $if1 | awk '{print $4}' | echo > $ipv4
/sbin/ip -o -4 addr show $if1 | awk '{print $6}' | echo > $bast
/sbin/ip -o -4 addr show $if1 | awk '{print $9}' | echo > $dhcp
/sbin/ip -o -6 addr show $if1 | awk '{print $4}' | echo > $ipv6

#print discovered info to screen
echo -e "---- Interface     = $if1"
echo -e "---- DHCP Enabled?   $dhcp"
echo -e "---- IPv4 Address  = $ipv4"
echo -e "---- Broadcast     = $bast"
```

Comment: honestly i haven't tried anything yet, as i haven't been able to understand anything i have googled.    the most complex line i have used so far in this prac has been.  "sudo nmap -sT -O localhost | grep open"

Comment: The [Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/) is a good place to start learning. The rest of that site is also pure gold, even if brusque. I'd advise to stay clear of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide. Also, `ip` is recommended over `ifconfig` these days, and it can produce much more easily parseable output.

Comment: Instead of `... | echo > $if1`, what you want is `if1=$(...)`, for example `if1=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr show up primary scope global | awk '{print $2}')`. You might want to read on shell [command substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution). I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well there's always `head`, `tail` and `cut`, but this might be easier:

```
echo `ifconfig wlo1` | 
{ read a b c d e inet f netmask g broadcast h inet6 i ; echo $inet $inet6 ; }
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.120 fe80::b400:3b2e:a40a:9f19
```

Notes:

- `read` names and sets the variables in one shot.  The `a b c d e` *etc.* are dummy variables used to absorb the unwanted `ifconfig` output.
- As soon as the `}` is run, the variables cease to exist.  So put any code that uses those variables *before* the `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ifconfig -a | tr -s ' ' | awk -F ' ' '{if (/^[a-z]/) printf  $1 " "} {if (/inet /) print " " $3" "$5" "$7} {if (/ether/) print " " $2"}'
```